# In Terminal, I can't remove Trashed Finder items deleted from other mounted volumes

Tags: command-line, external-hard-drive, finder, rm, trash

The scenario is as follows.
I run macOS A (APFS) which is an active partition. The macOS B&C (HFS+) are on mounted bootable volumes and visible while I'm working in macOS A. I can delete Finder items from those volumes with the standard Finder GUI command (the shortcut is ⌘-←) and see them in the macOS A Trash. I need to wipe them off completely with the **rm** command but it won't let me. In Terminal, I can list and count them but the removal operation fails without notice. The path of every item in Trash contains the name of the bootable volume on which one of macOS B&C is installed. When I do

`sudo rm -Rf /Volumes/macOS\ B/.Trashes/*`

with admin privileges from macOS A, it just runs dry. How do I remove these items with CLI?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. A *user id* caps the **correct** path to remove trashed items. If the user *id* is *501* then we have the command `sudo rm -Rfv  /Volumes/Volume_Name/.Trashes/501/*` which denotes the volume trash as opposed to user's one that has `$HOME/.Trash/` as its path.